# Block eval && new Function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just working on writing some random puzzles on codewars.com and am curious if anyone can think of a way to eval code after the following code has been run:

```
eval = function(){};
delete Function.prototype.constructor;
Function = undefined;

// the following are to block require('vm') -- if anyone wants to run this
// in production it may be better to block that one module (others?)
require = undefined;
module.__proto__.require = undefined; // added this due to alexpod's answer, modified due to Fabrício Matté's :)
module.constructor = undefined; // added this due to alexpod's answer
```

This is in node.js, so `setTimeout( "string" )` doesn't work.

Comment: You might be more successful posting this on a coding challenge site.

Comment: I assume this is for security measures? in this case it is a blacklist, as your question implies.

Comment: @Barmar I thought this was a coding challenge site?

Comment: @guest271314 -- what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: Do you have access to the `document`? If you do then you can inject a script using `var script = document.createElement("script"); script.innerHTML = "your code"; document.body.appendChild(script);`.

Comment: Oh, it's node.js. Nevermind.

Comment: @guest271314 -- I don't understand, that won't eval anything since the try will fail on "eval is not a function"

Comment: One possible solution would be to use a metacircular interpreter like [JS-Interpreter](https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/docs.html) to evaluate your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well,  also you have  `module` variable in `node`. So you can require `vm` package and run code using its `require` method:

```
var vm = module.require('vm');
vm.runInThisContext(' console.log("hello") ');
```

**UPD**
Well, you updated the question, but we can hack it again:

```
var vm = module.constructor.prototype.require('vm');
vm.runInThisContext(' console.log("hello") ');
```

**UPD2**
Another variant:

```
var vm = module.constructor._load('vm');
vm.runInThisContext(' console.log("hello") ');
```

**UPD3**
Again conditions are changed so the next variant:

```
module.constructor.prototype._compile(' console.log("again hacked") ');
// or
module.__proto__._compile(' console.log("again hacked") ');
// or
Object.getPrototypeOf(module)._compile(' console.log("again hacked") ');
```

I think better to set `module = undefined` to make question more complex:)

**UPD4**
There are another variant without `module`:)

```
process.stdin.push(' console.log("here we are") \n ');
```

But it works only in CLI ("repl")

**UPD5**
Also in `iojs` and in `node` with version >= 0.11.x you can use `contextify` binding:

```
var contextify = process.binding('contextify');
var script = new contextify.ContextifyScript(' console.log("im here, buddy") ');
script.runInThisContext();
```

In `node` with version < 0.11.x you can use `evals` binding:

```
var evals = process.binding('evals');
var script = new evals.NodeScript(' console.log("here I am") ')
script.runInThisContext();
```

Comment: Upvoting, and will later accept since this is the first correct answer :)  Waiting for more answers though :D

Comment: @zyklus You changed the condition of question :)

Comment: Yes, because I want as many answers as possible.  Yours is correct, I'm not disputing that :)

Comment: @zyklus add `module = undefined` to the question, to do it more complex

Comment: @zyklus Oou, didn't notice Fabricio's answer

Comment: @alexpods is your update correct? I get "Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined" when applying OP's code.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Hmm, are you sure, you didn't do "module = undefiend"?

Comment: what the hell is `module.constructor._load`?  :)

Comment: @zyklus I updated answer for `module.__proto__.require = undefined;` condition

Comment: @alexpods did you run `delete Function.prototype.constructor;` before your code? The first "UPD" will fail due to it I believe.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté well `require` is not a `constructor` I think. And yes after `module.__proto__.require = undefined` this is not working anymore.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté -- module doesn't seem to inherit from `Function`?  It has it's own constructor it seems

Comment: @zyklus `module.__proto__ === require('module').prototype`

Comment: @zyklus new variant are added.

Comment: :)  - Changed to `module.constructor = undefined`, which I think fixes the last couple?

Comment: @zyklus Oough, yes, I didn't notice this :(

Comment: I changed it after your last update ;)  You're good at finding these!

Comment: @zyklus Yeah, but it exists only in console (repl), so it's not a fully solution

Answer (score 4):

`module.require = undefined;` is not enough as `require` is inherited from the Module prototype:

```
module.require = undefined;

var vm = module.__proto__.require('vm');
vm.runInThisContext('console.log(1)');
```

Instead, you should:

```
module.__proto__.require = undefined;
// now this fails and you can't use the __proto__ trick:
var vm = module.require('vm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [GeneratorFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/GeneratorFunction) constructor:

```
(function*(){}).constructor('console.log(1);')().next().value;
```